# React native Deprecated Gradle features when Builing apk

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to build my apk using `./gradlew bundleRelease` but I always get this error:

```
error EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'P:\React'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'P:\React'

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

I also tried `./gradlew app:assembleRelease` but I get the same error. I also created my project using npx.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything, I even updated the project gradle verion but I would still get the same error. But the solution was just this:

```
cd android
```

clean your gradle:

```
./gradlew clean
```

then:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```